# Perl win32::GUI progressbar

Tags: perl, winapi

Progress bar is not following the script. I want to display progressbar as the script executes. when it done it should stop. currently it is displying full process then going for printing output.
Please find my code below:

```
$Progress_bars = $main->AddProgressBar(
   -pos        => [10,840],
   -background => [0,255,85],
   -smooth     => 1,
   -size       => [470,20],
);
my $intended_max = 100;
my $x = 11;
my $y = int($intended_max/$x);
$Progress_bars->SetRange(0,$x*$y);
for (1 .. $x) {
    Win32::GUI::DoEvents();
    $Progress_bars->SetStep($y);
    $Progress_bars->StepIt();
    Win32::Sleep(50);
}

$output = $telnet->print('ls');
print $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're code is increasing the value by the progress value rather than setting it directly.
Try calling the `SetPos` methods instead of `SetStep` and `StepIt`.

(Note that I don't use Win32::GUI, so I'm guessing the method name based on MSDN.)